# Input of Inputfields gets stored and send to server as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rest, routes

Hi this is my first Webproject for school so I might not get everything right away.
When I submit the form on the client-side, the input values from the form fields are being sent to the server as "undefined," and so that I am not able to store the data or update the contributions div with the new entry.

The server-side code is implemented using Node.js and Express, while the client-side code uses HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.

```
<body>

<header>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('header').load('navbar.html');
        });
    </script>
</header>

<div id="container">

    <form id = "kontaktFormular" action="/forum/beitrag" method = 'POST'>
        <h1>Forum</h1>

        <input id ="thema" type="text" name="tit" placeholder="Thema" required>
        <input id ="beitragTextfeld" type="text" name="contr" placeholder="Sagen Sie uns Ihre Meinung!" required>

        <button type="submit">Abschicken</button>

    </form>

    <div id=" beitraege">
        <p id = contributions></p>
    </div>

    <script>

        // Function to fetch and update the entries
        async function updateEntries() {
            const response = await fetch('/forum/beitrag');
            const entries = await response.json();

            const entryList = document.getElementById('contributions');
            entryList.innerHTML = '';

            entries.forEach(entry => {
                const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                listItem.textContent = `Date:${entry.datum} Title: ${entry.thema}, Contribution: ${entry.beitrag}`;

                entryList.appendChild(listItem);
            });
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', updateEntries);


        document.getElementById('kontaktFormular').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
            const tit = formData.get('tit');
            const contr = formData.get('contr');

            const response = await fetch(event.currentTarget.action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });

            const updatedEntries = await response.json();

            updateEntries(updatedEntries);
        });

    </script>
</div>

</body>
```

Serverside:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = 8000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static('.'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/forum/beitrag', (req, res) => {
    res.send(entryData);
    console.log("posted");
});

let entryData = [
    {datum: "10.Juni.2023", thema: "mein beitrag", beitrag: "digga warum geht das nicht"}];

app.post('/forum/beitrag', (req, res) => {

    const { tit, contr } = req.body;
    console.log({ tit, contr });
    const newEntry = {datum: createDate(), thema: tit, beitrag: contr};

    entryData.push(newEntry);

    res.json(entryData);
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {

})

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(` app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I've tried to check for typos and checked if I'm using the right modules.
When I've console.loggged the received data on the Serverside I can see that it's empty/both values are undefined.

Comment: After the line of `const tit = formData.get('tit');` what is the value of your `tit` constant just created?

Comment: hey,  for both `const tit = formData.get('tit'); and const contr = formData.get('contr');` the input seems to be stored these constants.

Comment: Can you check the network tab of your browser and tell me what do you see in the payload of the request?

Comment: From what I can see on the payload tab of my browser, the contents include the input I've typed in.

Comment: Sorry, let me describe it in more detail. When I submit the form, two tabs appear to the left of my payload tab (named "name"), one of which contains the value, while the other remains empty.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extracting the items, you can build an object and pass it to `JSON.stringify`. Proof-of-concept:

```js
document.getElementById('kontaktFormular').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
            const tit = formData.get('tit');
            const contr = formData.get('contr');
            console.log(JSON.stringify({tit, contr}));

        });
```

```html
<form id="kontaktFormular">
    <input type="text" name="tit">
    <input type="text" name="contr">
    <input type="submit" value="click me">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've now come up with the following:

Comment: @unknown you are welcome. If my answer led you towards the solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer. Or you could accept your own answer as the correct answer, depending on which led you towards the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I've now come up with the following:

```
document.getElementById('kontaktFormular').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const tit = event.currentTarget.elements['tit'].value;
        const contr = event.currentTarget.elements['contr'].value;
        
        const data = {
            tit: tit,
            contr: contr
        };
        
        const response = await fetch(event.currentTarget.action, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data) // Convert data object to JSON string
        });

        const updatedEntries = await response.json();

        updateEntries(updatedEntries);

    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).